# How are jemanden/jemandem abbreviated?

Tags: abbreviation

By googling and searching online dictionaries, I've found that the following abbreviations are used for *jemanden* and *jemandem*.

- *jmd.* (for both)
- *jdn*, *jdm.*
- *jmn*, *jmm.*
- *jen*, *jem.*
- *j-n*, *j-m.*

Is there a consensus of which abbreviation to use among authorities, such as the Duden paper dictionaries?

I am not looking for arguments regarding which would be better to use, but rather want to know which is actually used.

Comment: Second one is used in my dictionary.

Comment: @Gigili: Thanks, could you write which dictionary it is?

Comment: Collins.

Comment: Thanks. I just checked my Langenscheidt's ED-DE, and it uses "j-m".

Comment: The variety of abbreviations suggests the absence of a consensus, which isn't necessarily a bad thing. I prefer `j-n, j-m`. Note there is also `j-s`: jemandes Kleider, someone's clothes.

Comment: I use jm for jemand(en) and jmd for jemandem. The usual abbreviations of dictionaries are cumbersome and not fit for quick and short notes.

Comment: I've never encountered the ones with the hyphen, but the respective abbreivations without one: *jn.*, *jm.*

Answer (score 9):

[Duden](http://www.duden.de) (and other dictionaries including [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/)) use the abbreviations

```
Nom.  jemand    jmd.
Gen.  jemandes  jmds.
Dat.  jemandem  jmdm.
Akk.  jemanden  jmdn.
```

Other dictionaries (e.g. [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/)) write:

```
Nom.  jemand    jd.
Gen.  jemandes  jds.
Dat.  jemandem  jdm.
Akk.  jemanden  jdn.
```

And... I found the following alternative in an old Langenscheidt dictionary (German-Italian):

```
Gen.  jemandes  j-s
Dat.  jemandem  j-m
Akk.  jemanden  j-n
```

Comment: The OP mentioned kinds of abbreviations, but which one is the most common abbreviation type? you mean the most common form is the one which the most reliable or famous dictionary uses?

Comment: So the answer is "no"? :)

Comment: The "Duden" is the most known German dictionary. It's a de-facto standard, but that doesn't mean that the other versions are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The **print edition** of the Duden (24 ed 2006) does not list any of these abbreviations. Therefore, if you use them in a (formal) document it may be appropriate to explain them in a list of abbreviations.

For abbrevations in general Duden writes:

> Bei Abkürzungen, die nur in geschriebenen Texten verwendet werden, wir meist keine Beugungsendung gezeigt.

**Abbreviations are usually written without showing the conjugation ending.**

However there are exceptions of this rule than may be applied to avoid missunderstandings:

- If the abbreviation ends with the last letter of the abbreviated word we may add the ending at the end of the abbreviation:

> die Bde. = *die Bände*

- For abbreviated names the ending is set after the abbreviating dot:

> B.s. Werke = *Brechts Werke*

- Sometimes plural forms are built by doubling of letters:

> Jgg. = *Jahrgänge*

---

**Note:**

Even though the 24th edition of Duden does not **list** the abbreviation for *jemand* they do   use them occasionally in this edition in the form of `jmd.`, `jmdn.`, or `jmdn.`.

Comment: It surprises me that none are listed. How does your Duden list constructions like "sich mit jemandem treffen"?

Comment: It's not the grammar Duden, it's the *Die deutsche Rechtschreibung 1*. I was surprised too, as many other abbreviations are listed. The online Duden (see @splattne's answer) knows them.

Comment: I guess, Paper dictionaries usually don't use the abbreviated form of "jemanden/jemandem". My [collins](http://www.collinslanguage.com) paper dictionary writes it as a complete form, but the online collins dictionary uses abbreviation form "jdn/jdm".

Comment: The 20th edition (1991) uses abbreviations: http://twitpic.com/56v08a

Comment: @splattne: I did have a closer look to ed 24 Duden: obviously they do use these abbreviations but don't explain them. Very inconsistent - looking forward to 25th edititon.

Answer (score 0):

Derartige Abkürzungen werden typischerweise in Wörterbüchern verwandt und dort auch im Glossar erklärt.

Außerhalb dieses Kontextes wirken diese Abkürzungen befremdlich. D. h., eigentlich muss man nachdenken, was gemeint sein könnte.

Im normalen Sprachgebrauch (Medien, Literatur und Korrespondenz) werden diese Begriffe meistens ausgeschrieben.